# Using RabbitMQ pika with a FastAPI service

Tags: rabbitmq, fastapi, pika

I have a FastAPI service, a light weight pass through service. On receiving a POST request, the
service publishes a message to a RabbitMQ queue.
Since the pika library is not thread safe, I will have to create a new connection for every request .
But the RabbitMQ documentation suggests otherwise - the recommendation is to use long lived connection(s) for an application, and channels for different threads/requests.

My application does not expect heavy loads, so is it alright to use the pika library and create a connection for every request ? Or, is rabbitpy a better library for my use case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the answer you're looking for but I have just had exactly the same problem and think I have solved it using the pika AsyncioConnection hooked into the asyncio event loop used by FastAPI.

The code is callback hell but you can hide it in a module.

[My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70889479/how-to-use-pika-with-fastapis-asyncio-loop)